# Implementing a custom ember-simple-auth Authenticator

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, keycloak, ember-simple-auth

Firstly, I am not a seasoned JS Developer, so please excuse obvious mistakes that I could have made.

I am trying to implement a custom Authenticator for authenticating a user with [Keycloak](http://www.keycloak.org/) using the OAuth2 Password Grant which requires the `client_id` be passed as part of the request body.

```
import OAuth2PasswordGrant from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant';
export default OAuth2PasswordGrant.extend({   
  serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8080/something/token', 
  makeRequest(url, data, headers = {}) {
    data.client_id = 'my-app';
    return this._super(url, data, headers);
  }
});
```

I have a controller that uses this Authenticator by calling this action:

```
actions: {
  authenticate() {
    let {username, password} = this.getProperties('username', 'password');
    this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oauth2', username, password).then(() => {
      // Do something
    }).catch((response) => {
      // Show error
    });
  }
}
```

This causes Firefox to hang and gives me an unresponsive script message.

If I remove the `return` from the `makeRequest()` method, I can see from the browser debugger that the call to Keycloak actually returns correctly with the object that contains my token etc. However ember inspector shows some errors related to unresolved promises. But I guess that's because I'm no longer returning the promise.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

**How can I fix the unresponsive script issue?**

**Is there another way for me to achieve my goal?**

**Edit 1: This is when I remove the return**

Here is the actual object that is returned:

```
{
"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJTRUNSd09fMlZWdGhxUVBUWnFxNHlqX0tKekxnOElSTjBrQkx5UTlacklrIn0.eyJqdGkiOiI1NDgzZDdkMi0zMDdhLTQyZjItYWUxZC0xYTZjMTZjOTM2ZjAiLCJleHAiOjE1MDgzMzE5MjAsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTA4MzMxNjIwLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvc2Z4LWl0cmFuc2Zlci13ZWItYWdlbnQiLCJhdWQiOiJhZ2VudC13ZWItYXBwIiwic3ViIjoiMzZiMWY4OWMtNGYwMC00OTU1LWE0YzMtZWQ0NzZmZDU2OGM3IiwidHlwIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwiYXpwIjoiYWdlbnQtd2ViLWFwcCIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MCwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjQwODMxZWFhLTRmMmEtNDk2ZS05NDVkLTdiZWIxN2U0NmU0NCIsImFjciI6IjEiLCJhbGxvd2VkLW9yaWdpbnMiOlsiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0MjAwIl0sInJlYWxtX2FjY2VzcyI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJ1bWFfYXV0aG9yaXphdGlvbiIsImJhY2stb2ZmaWNlLWFnZW50Il19LCJyZXNvdXJjZV9hY2Nlc3MiOnsiYWNjb3VudCI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJtYW5hZ2UtYWNjb3VudCIsIm1hbmFnZS1hY2NvdW50LWxpbmtzIiwidmlldy1wcm9maWxlIl19fSwibmFtZSI6IlVtYXIgS2hvbHZhZGlhIiwicHJlZmVycmVkX3VzZXJuYW1lIjoidW1hciIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJVbWFyIiwiZmFtaWx5X25hbWUiOiJLaG9sdmFkaWEiLCJlbWFpbCI6InVtYXJAYWlydmFudGFnZS5jby56YSJ9.eUJFklRiRjQPOC1rQLcqrljsSWmGXCpNNKqLJGAcvbnbwx8X0T1iqrmpFdyMN3EKRrIfTZyYRfcTEbpcBEjZcZtgDY9V0Ntvt4pvpUx_8Ey6I8xZQolHVwferjM30puLqG8MImADUimNrj3ghbJbAaCOJktIKgLnTIhDbkNb-8lzgbyq-rEP6lYAWjQ2OuOZnc8NQQ9CJiR9M1SB79SEmY2iQW9E_J8xo8BgZQ0GUBrhaWPo-Kn4RnlEcRNzVnlLHQKi5FM7Zpov3SMQUbAeLat38V41y09ap2XVCy7MfL_7-TrSlMx0TLrhWqPgA5aaXbmsT9_vKOoXNZoJ9bWCuA",
"expires_in":300,
"refresh_expires_in":1800,
"refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJTRUNSd09fMlZWdGhxUVBUWnFxNHlqX0tKekxnOElSTjBrQkx5UTlacklrIn0.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.XgYSZWwfaHeY1yZZuwnQ5bj-0IHP4UEmiPTqaeCE1KVyjl3kZz3HJVisndtcKPr05kalS-M_NqU0TaYvbcZ_zesJRIga5sz4gGRqObUmUCUJoQ_iWoOhbM2SutiVnlfgJDACvOxegIcSvakZTgQsEcSweio_0kMFqi-2DYzFp6Rl0TpQ8vALLkc7rEOonUGyt7S4qQzkT-xB1_ZDlSVfm6mC-QKYNZhtqBT18P7MKxBhEgwrJtCytA_4ft7qNAbgvZ3kUohcbhzxGvtHej5RKHNI2wTzwK3IWHbkLWNndxSk_Lzj2-lCx380VpTkVpiDJfq5umjskOmI13dyPF7paA",
"token_type":"bearer",
"not-before-policy":0,
"session_state":"40831eaa-4f2a-496e-945d-7beb17e46e44"
}
```

This is what ember inspector (Promises) shows:

[image]

Here is the stacktrace from the Promise:

```
Ember Inspector ($E):  authenticate/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:77927:9
initializePromise@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63591:7
Promise@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:64067:35
authenticate@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:77919:14
authenticate@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:78528:14
authenticate@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:79420:14
authenticate@http://localhost:4200/assets/sfx-itransfer-web-agent.js:855:9
join@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:20249:24
run$1.join@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:37657:12
makeClosureAction/</<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29073:16
exports.flaggedInstrument@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:37087:14
makeClosureAction/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29072:15
submit/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70453:20
tryCatch@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63549:14
invokeCallback@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63562:15
publish@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63532:9
@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:54458:16
invoke@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:19948:17
flush@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:19827:25
flush@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:20019:25
end@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:20128:26
run@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:20212:21
join@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:20219:24
run$1.join@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:37657:12
handleEvent/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:58233:18
exports.flaggedInstrument@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:37087:14
handleEvent@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:58232:17
_Mixin$create.handleEvent@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:57385:12
_bubbleEvent@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:57685:14
setupHandler/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:57619:20
dispatch@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:5546:16
add/elemData.handle@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:5355:6
```

Comment: I don't see a bug in the code you provided. You may need to post the error message output. The fact that Firefox is hanging is strange, there must be an infinite loop or something similar occurring - promises by themselves don't cause this.

Comment: It is quite odd. I have added some more debugging information to the question

Comment: why would you not set `clientId` like `serverTokenEndpoint` is seted?

Comment: `clientId` is not an attribute on `OAuth2PasswordGrant` as `serverTokenEndpoint` is.

Comment: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/1.4.0/addon/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant.js#L45

Comment: Sorry, that `clientId` is sent as part of the header and not the form data. My authentication server ie. Keycloak needs it a part of the form body

Comment: See https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/1.4.0/addon/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant.js#L120

Answer (score 1):

Actually you solution looks like right.

I guess you have a problem in server response or mismatch request methods **GET**/**POST**. To solve this try to debug promise inside `makeRequest`.

```
    return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(url, options).then((response) => {
    response.text().then((text) => { //<-- here debug text 
      let json = text ? JSON.parse(text) : {};
      if (!response.ok) { //<-- and here debug response 
        response.responseJSON = json;
        reject(response);
      } else {
        resolve(json);
      }
    });
  }).catch(reject);
```

So if problem will here, just rewrite whole method of `makeRequest` and add you own promise with custom `fetch`.

Another way is to write custom `Authenticator`, overriding `authenticate`, `restore` and (optionally) `invalidate` methods as wrote in documentation: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#implementing-a-custom-authenticator

Comment: So I have in fact tried rewriting the entire method with my own promise. Same result. I do not think there is an issue with the Request/Response as it returns correctly, I can see the object returned from the server. My next step would be to write a custom `Authenticator` I guess.

Comment: Are you sure `else` section with `resolve(json)` from code above really executed and contain `json` you can see object here or in browser debugger?